# ¿Cómo puedo crear un fichero txt con javascript y llenarlo con un string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

la cosa es que tengo una cadena de texto y quiero crear un fichero y guardarla ahí. Sólo necesito eso, saber cómo crear el fichero y guardar la cadena.
Buscando lo único jugoso que he podido encontrar es esto:

```
function WriteFile() 
{
   var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"); 
   var fh = fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\Test.txt", true); 
   fh.WriteLine(miCadenaDeTexto); 
   fh.Close(); 
}
```

Pero no funciona. ¿Alguien tiene una solución?

Comment: Vale, nada, lo he solucionado más sencillo así.

`var error = new File(["Mi cadena de texto"], "error.txt");`

Answer (score 2):

Cambia

```
var fso  = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

Por

```
var fso  = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403912/create-a-text-file-using-javascript